# Setting binmode on PHP sockets

Tags: php, sockets, binmode

I am reading binary data from a network socket in PHP. [With files, you can use the '*b*' mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to specify that the file is binary and should be read as such, but how does one mark a network socket as being binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network sockets are always assumed to be binary data, so the flag's not necessary. The "binary" name for the flag on file-based operations is somewhat badly chosen. It should be the "do not translate line-ending characters" flag.

Otherwise the obvious reading would be that if you don't specify `b`, the file should be read in analog mode.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that my issue was due to some unexpected buffering on the socket, not because the data I was getting was encoded in a funny way.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) is how php read binary data.

```
//example:
$un = unpack("V",$some_bin_string);
```

Comment: And this reads data from a socket without doing EOL char translations... how?